# Terminology: Compact subset of a subset

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Example: $P$ is tight, that is, $\exists K, P(K)>1-\epsilon, \forall \epsilon>0$ where $K$ is compact subset of $X$, if and only if for every subset $A$, $P(A)=\sup_K P(K)$ where sup is over all compact subset $K$ of $A$.

Is "compact subset $K$ of $A$" here (i) a compact subset of $X$ that is contained in subset $A$ or (ii) intersection of a compact subset of $X$ with $A$?

Comment: This is a little hard to answer definitively without wider context, but my instinct is definitely to interpret it in the first sense: it's a subset of $A$, and it is compact in the wider space.

Comment: @Theo Bandit is correct, but compactness is not a relative property. There is no "compact in the wider space." The set is compact as a subspace of either $X$ or $A$ since the topology on $K$ induced by either is the same.

Comment: In English  a consecutive string of adjectives followed by a noun all apply to that noun. So "compact subset K ..." means "K is compact and  K is a subset (of ...)"

Answer (score 1):

compactness is absolute. There is no compact "in $X$", but just compact (always considered as a space in its own right, so in the subspace topology).

So a compact subset of $A$ is just a set $K \subseteq A$ that is compact (as a space on its own).